# Why does my javascript function return null?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that searches the cookies string for a specific cookie and returns its value but I don't understand why it keeps returning null when the cookie exists.

```js
document.cookie = "userName=nameHere";
function getCookie() {
    document.cookie.split(";").forEach(cookie => {
        if (cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf("=")) == "userName") {
            var name = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1);
            console.log(name);
            return name;
        }
    })
    return null;
}

>> getCookie()
//prints
nameHere
//returns
null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a closer look you will see that there are actually 2 functions.

```
    `.forEach(cookie => {`
```

You actually returning `name` in the arrow function

A solution could be to go with a `for` loop instead of `forEach`

Comment: got it to work, thanks. I tried assigning forEach to a value like `var x = forEach(...{ })` but that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note here:

- forEach does not and is not supposed to return anything
- your function is returning null because you told it to return null
- don't hard code the name of the cookie you're looking for in the function, pass it as a parameter

That said, here is a working function:

```
document.cookie = "userName=nameHere";
function getCookie(cName) {
      const decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie) // deal with any special character
      // returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function
      const cookie = decodedCookie.split(";").find(c => c.substring(0, c.indexOf("=")) == cName)
      if (!cookie) return null // cookie not found, return
      const value = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1)
      return value
    }

console.log(getCookie('userName'))
```

Comment: I found out that forEach doesn't return anything so it's strange that it doesn't throw a syntax error, but also I like your use of .find

Answer (score -2):

My guess is that:

```
var name = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1);
```

doesn't actually assign a name. Try putting an Alert,  after the name var or log the name to check the contents.